# Why does Sqlite tell me no such column exists when I plainly created it?

Tags: python, sqlite

in Python 2.6.5 with sqlite3.version 2.4.1, I use the following code:

```
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''create table stocks
(date text, trans text, symbol text,
 qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("""insert into stocks
          values ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)""")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

c.execute('''insert into stocks values(date=?, trans=?, symbol=?, qty=?, price=?
)''', ('08-26-1984', 'SELL', 'GOGL', 3, 400.00))

# We can also close the cursor 

if we are done with it
c.close()
```

And it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbtest.py", line 18, in <module>
    c.execute('''insert into stocks values(date=?, trans=?, symbol=?, qty=?, price=?)''', ('08-26-1984', 'SELL', 'GOGL', 3, 400.00))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: date
```

My question - what the heck??? I created a column with the name "date"! I've spend the last two hours trying to figure out what in the world is wrong and I'm getting really frustrated. Also, when I try to open it by command line, I'm told:

> Unable to open database "orders": file
>   is encrypted or is not a database

ANY help would be greatly appreciated as I'm about to put my computer through a wall.

Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's a bad idea to give a column a name that matches a keyword in either your database or in the language you're using to write to it.  I don't actually think that's your problem here, but in the future naming a column 'date' will probably bite you somewhere.

Comment: That's useful advice - I just pulled the example creation code from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Incorrect [syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for that insert statement. This will work:

```
>>> c.execute('''insert into stocks 
                 (date, trans, symbol, qty, price)values(?,?,?,?,?)''', 
                 ('08-26-1984', 'SELL', 'GOGL', 3, 400.00))
```

Comment: Go figure >.< I spent the summer months writing SQL queries for Microsoft SQL Server, so (as usual), I just thought "I know how to do this". The error message isn't exactly the most useful (and is kinda misleading, IMO). Thanks for the correction - I just wish I had learned a few hours earlier!